# Should I be worried about 98°C CPU temperature on MacbookAir?

Tags: macbook-pro, homebrew, temperature, cpu

I'm a developer and often times I need to compile some packages or maybe even run some codes for couple of hours.

Recently I have noticed that whenever I use `Homebrew` to install something, it defaults to source, and compilation causes my CPU temp to go around 98 Celsius . Some of the compiles are quite long, couple of minutes, and I'm worried this might harm my MacBookAir.

1. Should I be worried about this 98°C CPU temperature on MacbookAir?
2. And if so, how can I fix that?

Comment: Is the temperature 98 degrees Celcius of Fahrenheit?

Comment: @ProBackup Its Celsius

Comment: That seems quite hot. Even under stress, by 2011 15" MBP does not get hotter than 80°C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Michiel's correct in that if the computer gets too hot, it'll shut down automatically. However, if you want to be on the safe side, you can check out [smcFanControl](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23049/smcfancontrol) and [Fan Control](http://www.lobotomo.com/products/FanControl/).

### smcFanControl:

> smcFanControl lets the user set the minimum speed of the build in fans. So you can increase your minimum fan speed to make your Intel Mac run cooler. However in order not to damage your machines smcFanControl doesn't let you set a minimum speed to a value below Apple's defaults ([MacUpdate](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23049/smcfancontrol)).

### Fan Control

> Some MacBooks and MacBook Pros are just to hot for daylong use. Fan Control adjusts the minimum fan speed depending on the current CPU temperature. For safety, it leaves the original automatic fan speed control intact ([lobotomo](http://www.lobotomo.com/products/FanControl/)).

And remember, if your computer ever gets to 660.4°C, don't leave it on your lap, unless you want liquid aluminum all over you.

**UPDATE:**

I found another tool called [CoolBook](http://www.coolbook.se/CoolBook.html) that

> lets you monitor the frequency, voltage and temperature of the CoreDuo / Core2Duo CPU. Registered users can also change the frequency and voltage of the processor.

Here's a list of features that are listed on the [site](http://www.coolbook.se/CoolBook.html):

- Reduce heat (presumably by optimizing fan speed)
- Reduce fan speed (presumably by lowering fan speed)
- Extend battery life
- Improve performance
- Fine tune your CPU

This seems like a useful tool, but it does not support Lion and Mountain Lion, and does not work on Intel i3, i5, and i7 processors.

Comment: Here's a question. I installed smcFanControl, and it always remain at 2000 even when temp goes above 90. It was not like this in Lion ... (I have ML now)

Comment: @GradGuy - Did you actually configure it?

Comment: Configure smcFanControl? not really its on default

Comment: @GradGuy - I think it doesn't actually do anything without being configured.

Comment: oh yeah. I figured I could manually increase the fan speed. What I'm saying is shouldn't OS itself increase the fan speed when temp is around 90?!

Comment: @GradGuy - This is completely a guess, but maybe there are some risks to increasing the fan speed past a certain point because the hardware could be faulty or something like that, and that's why Apple doesn't increase it beyond a certain point.

Answer (score 2):

A MacBook Air gets hot, just like any other laptop, although 100°C is relatively hot (if not, almost the maximum a Mac can handle).
There are reports where users complain about their MacBook Air temperature [flirting with 100°C](http://9to5forums.com/discussion/2390/how-hot-does-a-macbook-air-get), so you're not alone.

Things you can do to prevent getting the Mac too hot is making sure you haven't covered his ventilating holes. Place it on a flat, hard surface (no lap, pillow or blanket as developers tend to do. At least, that's what I do once in a while :-)).
Other things you can do is make sure you don't run too much applications at the same time, or you could use a laptop stand to get extra fresh air under your Mac.

Or if it's really bothering you, you can always invest in [a professional laptop cooler](http://www.coolermaster.com/category.php?category_id=16).

[image]

What you should keep in mind is the MacBook Air will shut itself down when there is any chance of damage.  
So you've got nothing to worry about. Your Mac won't get harmed.

Comment: Careful Michiel. That's in an ideal world. I've seen too many macs in the last 5 years burn themselves up. And by that I mean significant or irreparable damage to one or another component of the mobo. If the OP wants, he could run a test and leave it at the temp indefinitely and see how the machine protects itself… but I wouldn't recommend it… maybe the airs have a vastly superior method of self protection from heat. Most of the machines I've seen give in to heat/humidity were Powerbooks, Macbooks and Macbook Pros, from 2006 to late 2011 models. Only one was an Air and that was humidity.

Comment: "MacBook Air will shut itself down when there is any chance of damage. " - not really. The damage is not "always happens always above XXX degrees" kind thing. Computer parts have mean time between failures (MTBF) that often depends on temperature the part is being operated. So there is "a chance of damage", which increases with the temperature, and it is manufacturer's choice which temperature to allow/disallow.
https://www.eeweb.com/demonstrated-mtbf-and-temperature/

Answer (score 0):

Damage of the type that "computer just burns" is unlikely, as Macbooks have protections against overheating. What should be the concern is increasing aging rate. Computer parts have mean time between failures (MTBF) that often depends on temperature at which the part is being operated. So there is always "a chance of damage", which increases with the temperature, and it is manufacturer's choice which temperature to allow/disallow.

Another thing that is CPU temperature is 98 degrees, it is quite possible it has already thermal-throttled to avoid damage.

I would take some action to cool it down - clear the insides, replace thermal paste.

more info: [eeweb.com/demonstrated-mtbf-and-temperature](http://eeweb.com/demonstrated-mtbf-and-temperature)

Answer (score -1):

1. From my personal experience, there are risks with excessive heat. The CPU has relatively complete temperature control settings, such as frequency reduction, to protect it from burning out, but the motherboard does not have. And because the macbook fan is slow to respond to temperature increases, It is possible for the motherboard to burn out due to excessive temperature. Let me tell you something that happened to me.

   I never cared about macbook temperature before until the motherboard of my own macbook pro burned out. That day I put the computer on my stomach, laying in bed watching a movie, then for a split second the computer went black and I can't turn on it again. The next day I took it to the service center and the repairman told me the motherboard was broken. I used to expect it to at least automatically shut down when it got too hot, but it turns out that macbook pro does not have such a protection mechanisme. I think macbook air won't shut down with extreamly high temparature either.
2. If you want to reduce the temparature, it is recommended to use a fan control programs such as mac fan control(download link [crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control](https://crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control)) to increase the fan speed. It works fine so far. As I mentioned, the macbook fan is slow to respond to temperature increases. Fan control software can improve this problem by increasing the fan to high speed when the temperature is relatively high. But because I just tried one kind of fan control software(mac fan control), I cannot give more suggestions about how to choose a better fan control software.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Did you have a specific fan control application in mind, and can provide a link?

Comment: I'm just describing my experience to prove that macbooks are not as invulnerable as they say, "Your Mac won't get harmed." I also only tried one fan control software, it works fine so far. Download link https://crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control.

Comment: Please have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I read it but didn't find anything wrong. As I'm inexperienced, please clearly point out what is wrong in my answer so that I can improve it.

Comment: At least include the link directly into your answer so it doesn’t get lost in the comments.

Answer (score -3):

Don't worry about the temperature of your macbook... use it without any thought.

Comment: you essentially repeated the last paragraph of Michiel's answer above further without any sources. Also, see my comment to that answer.